# Unexpected Non-NULL return

Tags: c++, windows, taglib

I am playing with TagLib (on Windows, built with MingW). I am trying to get TagLib to recognize when there is no ID3v1 or ID3v2 information in an MP3 file. According to the [TagLib documentation](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib/api/classTagLib_1_1MPEG_1_1File.html#ebe5029bca925e9ed7002b00244c1240), the ID3v2Tag() function in an MPEG File object should return a NULL pointer when there is no ID3v2 information in the file.

Unfortunately, this is not occurring. I have some test MP3 files I have made that I use in my code (I have made the files available):

- **blank.mp3** ([download](http://storage.joelverhagen.com/taglib/tests/other/blank.mp3)), no ID3v1 or ID3v2 information at all. I can confirm this by doing a plain text search for "TAG" and "ID3" in the files binary content.
- **only_album_id3v2.mp3** ([download](http://storage.joelverhagen.com/taglib/tests/id3v2/only_album_id3v2.mp3)), has ID3v2 information (only the album is set)
- **only_album_id3v1.mp3** ([download](http://storage.joelverhagen.com/taglib/tests/id3v1/only_album_id3v1.mp3)), has ID3v1 information (only the album is set)

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <mpeg/mpegfile.h>
#include <mpeg/id3v2/id3v2tag.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Test." << endl;

    TagLib::MPEG::File a("tests/other/blank.mp3");
    TagLib::MPEG::File b("tests/id3v2/only_album_id3v2.mp3");
    TagLib::MPEG::File c("tests/id3v1/only_album_id3v1.mp3");


    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag * at = a.ID3v2Tag();
    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag * bt = b.ID3v2Tag();
    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag * ct = c.ID3v2Tag();

    cout << at->album() << endl;
    cout << bt->album() << endl;
    cout << ct->album() << endl;

    cout << "The program is done.";

    return 0;
}
```

Running this program should break, due to a NULL pointer error on `cout << at->album() << endl;`, but it runs just fine. Also, when I `cout << ct << endl;`, it returns a memory address.

Here is the output:

> Test.
>
> test album id3v2
>
> The program is done.

**EDIT:**
Here is a new test.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <mpeg/mpegfile.h>
#include <mpeg/id3v2/id3v2tag.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Test." << endl;

    TagLib::MPEG::File a("tests/other/blank.mp3");
    TagLib::MPEG::File b("tests/id3v2/only_album_id3v2.mp3");
    TagLib::MPEG::File c("tests/id3v1/only_album_id3v1.mp3");


    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag * at = a.ID3v2Tag();
    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag * bt = b.ID3v2Tag();
    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag * ct = c.ID3v2Tag();

    if(at == NULL)
    {
        cout << "at is NULL.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "at is not NULL.";
    }
    cout << endl;

    if(bt == NULL)
    {
        cout << "bt is NULL.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "bt is not NULL.";
    }
    cout << endl;

    if(ct == NULL)
    {
        cout << "ct is NULL.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ct is not NULL.";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The program is done.";

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output.

> Test.
>   at is not NULL.
>   bt is not NULL.
>   ct is not NULL.
>   The program is done.

Comment: What do you expect? An exception? You’re passing NULL values to a stream, which is not output in the console, if I see that correctly. Isn’t that expected?

Comment: Is the `The program is done.` really output? As I don’t see that in your source code.

Comment: @Kissaki, shouldn't `cout << ct << endl;` output a 0 to the stream if ct is NULL? Also, I fixed the code example to match the output. Before, I updated the output but not the code. Now they match

Comment: I’m not sure. Personally, printing nothing for a NULL would be more intuitive for me though. Dunno what the spec or anything says though. /e: Oh, that output is pretty interesting now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I examined TagLib's code briefly.

I know nothing about it and never used it, but the code looks buggy to me. Here's why -

In MPEG::File::read(), we are looking for a tag - `d->ID3v2Location = findID3v2();`. If it doesn't exist, it isn't added to the tags vector. This is the check - `if(d->ID3v2Location >= 0)`.

However, at the end of the function, just before returning, we have -

```
// Make sure that we have our default tag types available.
ID3v2Tag(true);
ID3v1Tag(true);
```

Now, `Id3v2Tag(create)` with a true parameter, actually calls `return d->tag.access(ID3v2Index, create);`. The access() function is -

```
template <class T> T *access(int index, bool create)
{
  if(!create || tag(index))
    return static_cast<T *>(tag(index));

  set(index, new T);
  return static_cast<T *>(tag(index));
}
```

So when `create` is true, we are creating a brand new, empty tag and placing it in the vector (using the `set()` function).

This means that no matter whether the file contains the tags or not, they are added to the vector. This isn't the documented behavior. Looks like a bug.

I don't know why these two lines are needed there - looking at the history of this file might hint as to why they were added, but I didn't do that.

Anyway, I want to stress that I never actually executed this code. This is based on purely statically reading only very small parts, without being aware of large scale issues.

I think that opening a bug report can't hurt.

Comment: To avoid possible errors, I didn't comment the two calls out, but rather added three additional functions that return a private boolean (hasID3v2, hasID3v1, hasAPE). Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I looked up the file history and it turns out these lines were introduced [5 years ago](https://github.com/taglib/taglib/commit/37e2d6293f6312fb1fa7383d42726dc10e733a27). Anyway, I am wondering how to check whether id3 tag is available, so I don't hurt the wrong file while saving (m4a for instance)?

Comment: I've submitted [a bug report](https://github.com/taglib/taglib/issues/250) just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Using a null pointer doesn't necessarily result in any error you can see; it's undefined behavior. It might appear to work, or it might do something really really weird.

In this case the compiler is probably generating a call to TagLib::ID3v2::Tag::album with the *this* pointer set to null, but even this is not guaranteed. What happens inside the function is anyone's guess.

If the function can return NULL, you should be explicitly checking for it and doing something different.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying and I updated my question to fit what you suggest. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Taglib create an "Empty" ID3v2Tag and ID3v1Tag in the object if the file do not have one.

Comment: To my understanding, this is only if you pass TRUE to an MPEG File object's ID3v2Tag() function.

Comment: Yes, but in the consructor of the class TagLib::MPEG::File call ID3v2Tag and ID3v1Tag, with the parameter as TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I am having simmilar problem and hopefully I've found workaround for ID3v1/ID3v2 presence checking.

It's method [`virtual bool TagLib::Tag::isEmpty() const`](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib/api/classTagLib_1_1Tag.html#3e5f0c8331fb4d29a50bc269e095a90e)